# Finding Matrix Parent Item in advanced pdf

Tags: netsuite

I need to find the parent item of every child matrix item in Advanced Pdf in netsuite.Is there any way to find the parent item from the child item

Comment: What is your context? Transaction? Packing Slip? Scripted render?

Comment: Transaction is the context

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.